# OperationalError at /admin/blogapp/post/220/change/ no such table: blogapp_post_likes?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I've made a django blog app and its  working fine. Now I'm trying to add a like feature to the blogs by the users.

I added a `likes` field in my **Post** model but as soon as I ran the makemigrations and migrations command and went into my django-admin and click on the Post model, I got this -no such table: blogapp_post_likes.

I'm learning from this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pkPRtQf6oQ8) and he also did the same thing but his migrations worked.

I've tried deleting the migrations folder from the project prior to the makemigrations and migration command but its not working.

Here's my `models.py` file-

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from PIL import Image

class Profile(models.Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    contact = models.CharField(max_length=12,blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_pictures', default='default.png')
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True,null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username}'

class Post(models.Model):

    author = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
    create_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User,related_name='post_likes',blank=True)

    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def approve_comments(self):
        return self.comments.filter(approved_comment=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('blogapp:post_detail',kwargs={'pk':self.pk})

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Comment(models.Model):

    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name='comments', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    text = models.TextField(max_length=264)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    approved_comment = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def approve(self):
        self.approved_comment = True
        self.save()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('blogapp:post_list')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: What happens when you run `makemigrations`?

Comment: It says 'No Changes Detected'